# Defining and assigning empty list to variable before usage

Tags: python

```
s = "text"
parts = [] # <<< why not just parts = 0
print id(parts) # 3074379948

parts = s.split()
print id(parts) # 3074380332
```

I saw this in several programs, but I can't undestand why. Because `parts` reference to different objects. So this is just for readabillity?

Comment: I'd say `parts = []` is better than `parts = 0`. It shows that `parts` is a list, even if it's the redefined later as a different list. Using `parts = 0` first would just add extra confusion as the type would be changed.

Comment: It may matter if s.split() raises an exception - in `finally` routine `parts` is always defined and is always a 'right' type. In your code snippet - it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the second part of the code, you see that the assignment that is happening is

```
parts = s.split()
print id(parts) # 3074380332
```

In the above, `parts` is expected to be a `list`, since it is the output of `.split`. It would thus be logical, to instantiate it with a value of the same kind, like `parts = []`, for maintaining coherence of the program.

---

Imagine a scenario, where the second part fails (example code), and you still want to do something with `parts`. If you instantiate this with any other value, your code becomes inconsistent logically, and may throw errors. If you did `parts = 0` below, it simply would've failed since then parts would not have been an iterable, and so on:

```
parts = [] # works
# parts = 0 # doesn't work
try:
    s = 0
    parts = s.split()
except:
    pass
for part in parts:
    print part
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is setting a default value, where the `parts` value is expected to be a list object, always.

Perhaps the `parts = s.split()` line is not always reached, but the `parts` variable is always used and expected to be a list. This could happen if there is an `if` statement, or a `try..except` or `try..finally` statement, or even in a loop where a `continue` or `break` statement will bypass part of the loop body.

It makes no sense to then set `parts = 0`, because an integer is not the same type of object. If the `s.split()` is always executed, you can omit the `parts = []` line altogether, it is then just redundant.